# path in openstreetmap or google maps based on path in svg

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, svg

I'm about to create an application that should try to create a path in openstreetmap or google maps based on a given path in a svg. For example, I've got the following svg:

[image: svg]

What tools to use and how to start such project? I've already checked overpass and openlayers. Nonetheless, it's not quite obvious for me how to start. One main problem for me is: How to determine the angle between two lines in osm or google maps? Or even: How to determine the angle of one single line? Let's take for example the only line above with the angle 135°. Determining a perfect vertical or horizontal line seems simple as the latitude or longitude keeps its value. But what about anything else?

Three important notes:

- the path in the svg can be scaled arbitrarily on the map. Thus, on a map the path can have a perimeter of 1 mile or 100 mile.
- the rotation of the path on the map can be arbitrary as well. It's about finding the **shape** of the svg-path which can also be rotated
- and even the shape can be distorted to a certain degree. This means, all the relative lengths of the lines to one another don't have to be perfectly exact. Even the angles can differ to some extent.

Are there any experts on this particular subject that could give me some helpful hints how to master that task?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend that you break your task down offline from here and then if/as you get stuck on particular steps research/ask them one at a time.

Comment: @PolyGeo: thx for your suggestion and sorry for my late response. I'm just trying to figure out some main problems in my development process and will get back to this topic later.